# render current_page after connect with facebook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I have blog app, and users can comment on blog if already logged in connect with facebook, I'm using omniaut-facebook gem.

I put a link connect w/ facebook on any `localhost:3000/blogs/:permalink`

**how to render current_page** when user click link connect w/ facebook on `localhost:3000/blogs/rails` and succeeded then render `localhost:3000/blogs/rails`

```
class User::SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render "localhost:3000/blogs/:permalink"
    end

end
```

how can I do it?
Please help me..

thanks for **who have closed** my quetions..

ok **problem solved**

```
origin = request.env['omniauth.origin']
redirect_to "#{origin}"
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  You are not saying what doesn't work.  You are not saying how you want it to work, but it isn't doing it.

Comment: how to render current_page when user click link connect w/ facebook on `localhost:3000/blogs/rails` and succeeded then render `localhost:3000/blogs/rails`

Comment: You're still asking how-to, but not including what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add some routes to handle the paths that OmniAuth uses.

**/config/routes.rb**

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'users/sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'users/sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

When Facebook redirects back to your app now, it will look for the create action in a SessionsController.

**/app/controllers/user/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class User::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

Comment: I've done was previously, how to back to `localhost:3000/blogs/:permalink`

Comment: Check the path of `/blogs/:permalink` by running `rake routes` and then use redirect_to. Probably if your path after running `rake routes` is `blog_path` then just do `redirect_to blog_path(params[:permalink])`

Comment: `:permalink=>nil`
thanks @saurabh, for sharing his knowledge with me..